# Writing map-reduce in python for hadoop

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing map-reduce in python, but i have sufficient knowledge for the same in java, i am trying to run map-reduce in hadoop environment which is written in python language

`bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -file /home/TEST/mapper.py -mapper /home/TEST/mapper.py -input /HADOOP/SourceFiles/input -output /home/hdfs1/HADOOP/my-output4`

and i am getting

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:112)
    in mapper.py
```

I want to know:

1) Like java is there any dependencies like jar and any package to run python mapper code.

2) I have used panda's in my mapper.py so how can i add tell hadoop to use panda while parsing the statement

3) I will share the code once i will have sufficient information that i am doing wrong in map.

Comment: Hadoop? Where is python involved? You mean spark?

Comment: No, i am writing mapper in python language to do some csv file manipulation

Comment: Using : bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file /home/TEST/mapper.py    -mapper /home/TEST/mapper.py -input /HADOOP/SourceFiles/input -output /home/hdfs1/HADOOP/my-output4 to run

Comment: I think there is no error in python side. Try to run the hadoop command in terminal which is define in python file. It will raise same error.

Comment: I didnt get, but here what i got suppose i added this line into my mapper.py:   import pandas as pd       than same error is generated if i am not using this no error occure. One more thing as i imported panda here where can i get this panda library or something to add into my classpath, guide me if i lost my path as i work with java i think same for python as well

Comment: Unindented text.

Comment: **all** hadoop nodes in the cluster must have pandas (or any module you import) installed on their PYTHONPATH. However, that's not related to the current error message. I will second the suggestion that you use Spark

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion